# Wrong symbol when using escape sequences learn python the hard way ex10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, console, control-characters

When i try to print \v or \f i get gender symbols instead:

[image: screenshot]

Note also that I'm a complete beginner at programming.

edit: Seems like i didnt write clear enough, i **dont** want to write \v or \f but the escape sequence created by them, i dont know what they exactly do but i dont think this is their meant function-

Comment: That's what you get in the windows console window if you print those control characters. what were you expecting?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: In Learn Python The Hard Way there is a list of escape sequences where it says:  "\f - ASCII formfeed (FF)" and "\v - ASCII vertical tab (VT)" Why do these come out as gender symbols?

Comment: Please check an answer as correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @dcarson,  what does `"\f"` output without printing?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print special characters, e.g., `"\n" == new line`. You can learn more here: [Python String Literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Excerpt:

> In plain English: String literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes (') or double quotes ("). They can also be enclosed in matching groups of three single or double quotes (these are generally referred to as triple-quoted strings). **The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.** String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.

The r tells it to print a "raw string."

Python 2.7ish:

```
print r"\v"
```

Or, you can escape the escape character:

```
print "\\v"
```

Or, for dynamic prints:

```
print "%r" % ("\v",)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel out `\` by using `\\` the `\` character is used for special cases.

try

```
print '\\t'
print '\\v'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `print '\\v'` or `print r"\v"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
print (r"\n")
```

**r** is good for escaping special characters.

Comment: this is not what the OP is asking

Comment: This prints a raw string, where no special characters are "invoked" or interpreted.